# Dynamic DataTable with Editable option

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to create a dataTable using primefaces 3.x dynamically with the ability to do the edit the entire cells as well. All the cell contents will be select box. IF i use "Columns" in primefaces i will be able to create dynamic columns but be able to create editable cells not able to ,please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems impossible at the moment.
From PM Manual.
Dynamic columns is handy in case you can’t know how many columns to render. Columns component is used to define the columns programmatically. It requires a collection as the value, two iterator variables called var and columnIndexVar. Features like sortBy and filterBy are supported however advanced features like **editing is not.**